# What are the different logs available in linux to track network activity?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, opensuse

I am using #openSuSE and I want to track all the network activities on my system like when the network goes down or up.Is there any log files other than var/log/messages that stores network activities information.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to OpenSuse documentation *[System log files are always located under the /var/log directory](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.logfiles.html)*

I do not know the Firewall install by default on OpenSuse but you should be able to log all network traffic using the Firewall (example with iptables : `iptables -j LOG` for all chains)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually yes, the network activities should be in /var/log/messages. Also check dmesg. You should look at syslog-ng.conf if you have that installed. Sometime sspecific log forwarding options are mentioned there. For instance this is what I have for dhcp.

`filter f_dhcpd { facility(local7); };
destination d_dhcpd { file("/var/log/dhcpd.log"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_dhcpd); destination(d_dhcpd); };`